# Something went wrong in my test with models, since I add a Dependency Injection

Tags: java, testing, gradle, cucumber, picocontainer

I try to make my test simpler with a DI (PicoContainer), but now it doesn't work corrctly anymore.

I get this errormassages:

---

java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.setRaw(Model.java:355)

at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.setInteger(Model.java:1740)

at cash_withdrawal.Account.(Account.java:11)

at support.TestAccount.(TestAccount.java:7)

....

---

**support.TestAccount:**

```
   public class TestAccount extends Account {
    public TestAccount() {
        super(1234);
        saveIt();
        }
    }
```

**cash_withdrawal.Account**

```
 public class Account extends Model {
    private TransactionQueue queue = new TransactionQueue();

    public Account() {}

    public Account(int number){
        setInteger("number", number);
        setString("balance", "0.00");
    }
}
```

**My Stepdefintion:**

```
public class AccountSteps {
TestAccount account;

public AccountSteps(TestAccount account) {
    this.account = account;
}

@Given("^my account has been credited with (\\$\\d+\\.\\d+)$")
public void myAccountHasBeenCreditedWith$(
        @Transform(MoneyConverter.class) Money amount)
        throws Throwable {
    account.credit(amount);
}
```

Comment: Remove the no-arg constructor in Account class and check if it works

Comment: Do you mean: public Account() {}


If I do this I get:

Comment: > Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\Users....IdeaProjects\cash_withdrawal\src\main\java\cash_withdrawal\AtmServer.java:42: error: constructor Account in class Account cannot be applied to given types;
        new AtmServer(9988, new CashSlot(), new Account()).start();
                                            ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length